# What is pooling in recurrent neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to know what max pooling and mean pooling are for recurrent neural networks like LSTM while using them for sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I think as far as I know we pooling is mostly used in convolution neural networks.
and it is a method of concentration of higher order matrix to lower order matrix which contains properties of inherent matrix...in pooling a matrix smaller size and is moved over the original matrix and max value or average value in smaller matrix is selected to form a new resultant matrix of further computation.  link-https://machinelearningmastery.com/pooling-layers-for-convolutional-neural-networks/